# How to do an if statement in excel

Tags: database, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to do an if and statement in excel for a query like this

```
 If $age = <65 and $income = <90,000 then - 27.82% from $premium
```

So far I've got

```
 =IF(AND(E4<65,F4 <90000), 800-27.82%)
```

but it just gives me

799.7218 as an answer when It should be giving me 577.44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IF(AND(E4 < 65, F4 < 90000), 800 * (1 - 0.2782))
```

Comment: How could I do this if I was trying to do a range something like this:

    If $age > 65 and $income = range(90000 to 105000) then 800 - 18.55% else NA

So far I've got 

    =IF(AND(E4 > 65, E4 <69, F4 > 90000, F4 < 105000), 800 * (1 - 0.1855),"NA")

I am getting NA when I'm trying to get 651.6. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Your "then" clause, the 800-27.82%,, is being interpreted as 800-0.2782, which is 799.7218.

If you want to reduce the value by 27.82%, you need to multiply it, like 800*(1-0.2782)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF( AND( E4 < 65, F4 < 90000 ), 800 - (0.2782 * A1 ) )
```

...where `A1` is your `$premium` value.